# Problems with vim-go and vimrc

Tags: linux, go, vim, vim-go

I recently installed vim-go from github via this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/fatih/vim-go.git ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go
```

and it all worked.

But I want to see the line numbers and do some stuff in the "global" vimrc file.

So I added `~/.vim/vimrc` and the options also work.

But now I can't use commands like `:GoRun` anymore ("No command"). If I remove the `vimrc`, it works again...

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Vim source a script at startup when you don't have a `vimrc` so that new or casual users get a slightly richer out-of-the-box experience. This is a laudable idea on paper but it broke a lot of things and caused the very issue you are having for a lot of people.

Case in point, filetype-specific plugins like vim-go rely on filetype detection being enabled. This is done by the script I mentioned above but you are on your own when you decide to create your own `vimrc`: the script in question is not sourced, so filetype detection is disabled by default, so filetype-specific plugins like vim-go don't work.

You can handle the situation in two ways:

1. source that script from your `vimrc`, as mentioned in `:help defaults.vim`:

   ```
   unlet! skip_defaults_vim
   source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
   ```
2. take full control of your config by adding what you need to your `vimrc`, as you need it:

   ```
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```

I would go with the second solution.